# How to execute multiple .bat files from different location using master.bat?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I want to execute multiple .bat files from different location using master.bat

I tried like

```
Master.bat

REM Echo Launch dir: "%~dp0"
REM Echo Current dir: "%CD%"
cd %~dp0\..\demo123\folder1\first.bat

REM Echo Launch dir: "%~dp0"
REM Echo Current dir: "%CD%"
cd %~dp0\..\demo555\folder2\second.bat
REM Echo Launch dir: "%~dp0"
REM Echo Current dir: "%CD%"
pause
```

it is only executing `first.bat` I want to execute all , I'm going to add 10 more files like with different folder location `Main` source folder is fixed. that is why i can use `..`

Comment: You need to "call" your other .bat files: `call ..\demo123\folder1\first.bat`

Comment: I tried using call also it is only executing first .bat file not below ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you want to have the files called.

One by one: use `call`, because otherwise that batch will take over and end the primary batch.

In parallel: use the `start` command

But I think you have an error in your batch: don't mix `cd` and calling a batch. Do this instead:

```
...
cd %~dp0\..\demo123\folder1
call first.bat
cd %~dp0\..\demo555\folder2
call second.bat
...
```

You could also call the batch with a complete path, but I believe that splitting into two lines makes the batch more readable.

Comment: It can be parallel but should have to execute all the listed .bat files.

Comment: both variants don't end your primary batch, so after executing first your batch still exists and is able to call the second and so on.

Comment: I think there is an issue with file location may be as I'm doing `cd` everytime and then using `call` or `start`. can you help me to correct my above `Mater.bat`?

Comment: you made it right I mixed `cd` and `call` now this is working perfect thanks

Comment: @Neo that's good news. You can accept the answer, so others will know they don't need to strive for an answer any longer

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to set the directory of batch files using `cd`

```
cd D:\Files
File1.bat
File2.bat
```